# Using a function defined inside an exports function, from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code like this in a file helperFunctions.js:

```
exports helperFunctions = () => {
    const functionA = async(args) => {
        console.log(args);
    };
    const functionB = async(args) => {
        functionA(myArg);
    };
}
```

How can I call `functionA` and `functionB` from a separate file altogether, say, main.js?

I've tried:

```
import { helperFunctions } from './helperFunctions';

//...some code

helperFunctions.functionA('hello');

// OR

functionA('hello');
```

The specific error is:

```
TypeError: _helperFunctions.helperFunctions.functionA is not a function
```

and when trying the second solution, it's:

```
ReferenceError: functionA is not defined
```

I'm trying to avoid importing literally every single function I'm using (by way of exporting every single function I'm using). I'd like to do something like `helperFunctions.function` for the functions I need.

Comment: You can't. Those functions are the values of local variables inside the single anonymous `=>` function exported. They cannot be used external to that context, unless there's more code (that you didn't post) that explicitly makes them available somehow.

Comment: You shouldn't make them local functions. You should export an object and make those functions properties of the object.

Comment: `helperFunctions` probably shouldn't be a function, it should be an object.

Answer (score 1):

It really need to be a function? You could export an Object:

```js
// helperFunctions.js
let helperFunctions = {
    functionA: async (args) => {
        console.log(args);
    },
    functionB: async (args) => {
        functionA(myArg);
    }
}

exports helperFunctions;
```